# Eclipse RCP: PreferenceStore data gets removed on restart, is this supposed to happen?

Tags: plugins, eclipse-rcp, preferences

I was under the impression that when I use the `IPrefrenceStore` of an `AbstractUIPlugin` I would be able to save information between restarts but that doesn't seem to be the case?

Storing some data:

```
private IPreferenceStore preferenceStore = FeaturePlugin.getDefault().getPreferenceStore();
preferenceStore.setValue("testKey", "SomeString");
```

Now restart the RCP and try tro recover the stored information:

```
private IPreferenceStore preferenceStore = FeaturePlugin.getDefault().getPreferenceStore();
preferenceStore.getLong("testKey")
```

Result is an empty String. Is this supposed to happen?

**Resolution:** If you kill your RCP while debugging the application, the preferences are not getting written since the `stop()` method of the corresponding plugin was never executed. Was a developing mistake on my behalf!

Comment: The preference store does need to be saved but this should happen automatically if the RCP is shutdown properly.

Comment: So the information should be available after restart?

Comment: Yes it should be available. Look in the workspace .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings directory for a xxx.prefs file - where xxx is the plugin id.

Comment: Such a file doesn't exist. Could it be that the scope is somehow set to Instance Scope instead of Configuration Scrope, because it works if I don't restart?

Comment: Configuration scope goes in the install configuration. Instance scope is correct here and goes in the workspace. AbstractUIPlugin always uses InstanceScope. How is the RCP shutdown?

Comment: Now we are getting closer. When the RCP is shutdown by clicking the generic X close button the information is not stored. If i use the close entry from the menu the information is saved.

Comment: Okay I really don't know what happened but now it also works for the close button...